# Inserting in the middle of a MySQL queue

Tags: mysql, data-structures, queue

I'm making an RSS reader with a script that periodically fetches new content. Each time the script fetches new content, it fetches content from 1 feed. I'm making a queue of feeds so that each time the script executes, it pops the first feed in the queue. However, since some feeds are more popular than others, the processed feed may not be pushed to the end of the queue. For popular feeds, I want to enqueue them in the middle of the queue so they get processed again sooner. If I use a MySQL table with an `id` column denoting the order of the queue, then I have to shift down each `id` after the enqueued item. Is there a way to implement a queue in MySQL so that I can insert a row in the middle of the queue without much overhead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all lets toss out the idea of implementing a queue in a database, we can do better. Instead of keeping each feed's location in the queue, we store when it was last retrieved (let's say the column name is `last_retrieved`) Then to get the next feed to update use a query something like:

```
SELECT * FROM feeds ORDER BY last_retrieved ASC LIMIT 1
```

Update the the feed's `last_retrieved` field when you're done. Then you only have to update one record for each update instead of all of them.

Now on the the prioritization, we want to add a priority field (let's say `priority` and we'll use an integer type). Now we can run separate queries for each priority level:

```
SELECT * FROM feeds WHERE priority = 0 ORDER BY last_retrieved ASC LIMIT 1
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM feeds WHERE priority = 1 ORDER BY last_retrieved ASC LIMIT 1
```

and then you decide in your code which one to do first based on the time and priority.

Finally, assuming that you aren't constantly running updates and can retrieve them as a batch and have the sleep for a while we can do even better:

```
SELECT * FROM feeds 
    WHERE (priority = 0 AND last_retrieved < time1)
        OR (priority = 1 AND last_retrieved < time2)
        OR (priority = 3 AND last_retrieved < time3)
```

Where time1, time2, and time3 are calculated as the current time minus the configured update frequency for that priority level.

Comment: If you want item I to be processed X elements from now, item J Y elements from now, item K Z elements from now, etc. this idea really has exactly the same problem as a simple id column.